# A KeyValuePair in Java

Tags: java, key-value

I'm looking for a KeyValuePair class in Java.
Since java.util heavily uses interfaces there is no concrete implementation provided, only the Map.Entry interface.

Is there some canonical implementation I can import?
It is one of those "plumbers programming" classes I hate to implement 100x times.

Comment: I'd recommend against using a generic KeyValuePair class.  Much better to define a domain-specific class with more informative accessors (e.g. getProductId(), getProductPrice()).

Comment: @Adamski: I disagree. We don't use domain-specific `Map` or `List` classes, why should this be any different? A KeyValuePair is just a Map with one entry.

Comment: @skaffman: Fair point but I think the concept of a generic Pair is more easily open to abuse than passing Collections around.  For example, if someone wants to return two values from a method it's tempting to return a Pair<X,Y> but typically this is indicative of an underlying design problem (e.g. Why aren't X and Y unified somehow anyway in the domain model if they're intrinsically related?)

Comment: @Adamski: Because it's not `<X,Y>`, it's `<Key,Value>`. He's not asking for an arbitrary `Pair` type, he's asking for a `KeyValuePair` type.

Comment: Despite this I would much rather pass around a single object instance in my code, potentially with a getKey() method defined; e.g. I prefer: processProduct(Product) to processProduct(KeyValuePair<Integer, Product>) where the Integer is the product ID.  I agree that KeyValuePair (i.e. Map.Entry) or even a generic Pair is useful within a method logic but I don't like it to "leak out" as a return type or be supplied as a method parameter; e.g. I never pass around Map.Entry.

Comment: if you are android programmer, just use Intent which has putExtra and GetExtra methods.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

The class [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) is generic and can be useful.

Comment: ...or AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry if appropriate.

Comment: So I should use `List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry>` correct?

Comment: Better use AbstractMap.SimpleEntry / AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry as base for your own, domain-specific class, to be OO. In the simplemost case, it is just giving a new name to class and the two elements.

Comment: In the interest of best practices, it should be noted that in most cases `java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>` should be used in order to program to interfaces. So you should be using `List<Map.Entry<K, V>>`, for example, for the same reason you wouldn't use `ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V>>` in the consuming code. The code that actually _creates_ the instance must use a concrete class, obviously.

Answer (score 112):

Android programmers could use [BasicNameValuePair](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html)

**Update:**

[BasicNameValuePair](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html) is now deprecated (API 22).
Use [Pair](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) instead.

Example usage:

```
Pair<Integer, String> simplePair = new Pair<>(42, "Second");
Integer first = simplePair.first; // 42
String second = simplePair.second; // "Second"
```

Comment: That's not just for Android programmers, it's any java program.

Comment: @doctor-oreo yes any java programmer could download jar from [hc.apache.org](http://hc.apache.org/) but android has those **built in**

Comment: Actually for Android users, a good choice is [android.util.Pair](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html).

Comment: @GalDude33 why is that? It's added in 5 api level.

Comment: This isn't a universally-available language feature and will require more than a standard JRE runtime. `Pair` comes from javafx.util, which introduces a dependency on JavaFX, such as OracleJDK, OpenJDK or OpenJFX. If you're using one of these Java runtimes then great, but  there's no trivial way to add this to a JRE installation with a Maven or Gradle dependency.

Answer (score 55):

The Pair class from Commons Lang might help:

```
Pair<String, String> keyValue = new ImmutablePair("key", "value");
```

Of course, you would need to include commons-lang.

Comment: url changes from time to time. I googled Pair Commons Lang" and found it. I removed the link to prevent further downvotes :-(

Comment: Since 1.6 there has been `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` - which makes the commons Pair redundant.

Comment: I prefer commons Pair personally - doesn't seem right to have to dig for a class inside of AbstractMap.  But if you don't want to depend on commons lang for some reason, I could see that.

Answer (score 14):

Use of [javafx.util.Pair](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) is sufficient for most simple Key-Value pairings of any two types that can be instantiated.

```
Pair<Integer, String> myPair = new Pair<>(7, "Seven");
Integer key = myPair.getKey();
String value = myPair.getValue();
```

Comment: This is available in Android (Support Library), too.

Comment: It is not available in server JDK (headless) or from Java 1.9 up.

Answer (score 13):

```
import java.util.Map;

public class KeyValue<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V>
{
    private K key;
    private V value;

    public KeyValue(K key, V value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey()
    {
        return this.key;
    }

    public V getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    public K setKey(K key)
    {
        return this.key = key;
    }

    public V setValue(V value)
    {
        return this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I like to use

[Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Example:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.setProperty("displayName", "Jim Wilson"); // (key, value)

String name = props.getProperty("displayName"); // => Jim Wilson

String acctNum = props.getProperty("accountNumber"); // => null

String nextPosition = props.getProperty("position", "1"); // => 1
```

If you are familiar with a hash table you will be pretty familiar with this already

Comment: Properties are based on HashTable, and for a simple pair a HashTable is probably to expensive

Comment: As long as all you need is `<String, String>` Properties is best OTS class.  If you need `<String,Object>`, then best to back down the chain for a better solution

Comment: I took a really long break from Java. I messed around with some other keyvalue options awhile but was having issues so I googled for a better idea and ended up here and using my own answer from 5 years ago haha.

Answer (score 5):

You can create your custom KeyValuePair class easily

```
public class Key<K, V>{

    K key;
    V value;

    public Key() {

    }

    public Key(K key, V  value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setKey(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is

```
HashMap<Type1, Type2>
```

All you have to do is specify the datatype for the key for Type1 and the datatype for the value for Type2. It's the most common key-value object I've seen in Java.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: You seem to have missed part of his qualifications in this question.  A collection does not fit the need of a single key value pair.  He mentions the type of single Map entry, `Map.Entry<K,V>` but wanted a more general case.  This type can be instantiated directly though, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3110563/3251909

Comment: Big problem with this is that hashmap does not preserve the order.

Answer (score -1):

I've published a [`NameValuePair`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.globalmentor/globalmentor-core/latest/com/globalmentor/model/NameValuePair.html) class in [GlobalMentor's core library](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.globalmentor%20AND%20a:globalmentor-core), available in Maven. This is an [ongoing project](https://bitbucket.org/globalmentor/globalmentor-base/) with a long history, so please submit any request for changes or improvements.

Comment: Can someone explain why this was marked down? The OP asked for a name-value pair class. I provided one option. Perhaps mine is not your favorite, but how is it any less worthy for inclusion here than from from the other libraries indicated in the other answers? (Note that I did however just update the links, as one was broken due to repository reshuffling.)

Answer (score -1):

```
Hashtable<String, Object>
```

It is better than `java.util.Properties` which is by fact an extension of `Hashtable<Object, Object>`.