# Java - How to create new Entry (key, value)

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, key-value

I'd like to create new item that similarly to `Util.Map.Entry` that will contain the structure `key`, `value`.

The problem is that I can't instantiate a `Map.Entry` because it's an interface.

Does anyone know how to create a new generic key/value object for Map.Entry?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can just implement the `Map.Entry<K, V>` interface yourself:

```
import java.util.Map;

final class MyEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
    private final K key;
    private V value;

    public MyEntry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V setValue(V value) {
        V old = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        return old;
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = new MyEntry<String, Object>("Hello", 123);
System.out.println(entry.getKey());
System.out.println(entry.getValue());
```

Comment: Can you please explain why some implementations of Map has key as final (like in HashMap,ConcurrentHashMap), but not in some other implemementations like TreeMap,WeakHashMap?

Comment: The given code is not fully correct since it doesn't override equals and hashCode too which is required by interface Map.Entry

Comment: As of Java 7 Update 80, I have implemented above and it worked ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ECCcd6R6)). No other methods were overridden.

Comment: @silver, only because seems to be working in some scenario, doesn't mean that is right. in a hash algorithm for instance, proper equais() and hashCode() implementations are used by consistency and performance.

On a HashMap we are talking about performance and efficiency. On a TreeMap, can even drive to bugs.

Comment: @Rena If you need it, implement it. If you don't. Then don't. Simple.

Answer (score 975):

There's [`public static class AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html). Don't let the `Abstract` part of the name mislead you: it is in fact *NOT* an `abstract` class (but its top-level [`AbstractMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html) is).

The fact that it's a `static` nested class means that you *DON'T* need an enclosing `AbstractMap` instance to instantiate it, so something like this compiles fine:

```
Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry =
    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>("exmpleString", 42);
```

As noted in another answer, Guava also has a convenient `static` factory method [`Maps.immutableEntry`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#immutableEntry-K-V-) that you can use.

---

You said:

> I can't use `Map.Entry` itself because apparently it's a read-only object that I can't instantiate new `instanceof`

That's not entirely accurate. The reason why you can't instantiate it directly (i.e. with `new`) is because it's an [`interface Map.Entry`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).

---

#### Caveat and tip

As noted in the documentation, `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` is `@since 1.6`, so if you're stuck to 5.0, then it's not available to you.

To look for another known class that `implements Map.Entry`, you can in fact go directly to the javadoc. From [the Java 6 version](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

> ### Interface Map.Entry
>
> **All Known Implementing Classes**:
>
> - [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html), [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html)

Unfortunately the [1.5 version](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) does not list any known implementing class that you can use, so you may have be stuck with implementing your own.

Comment: The above line returns compilation error for me (I am using java 5, BTW) - error message is: 'The type AbstractMap.SimpleEntry is not visible'

Comment: That's because `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` wasn't public until Java 6, as you can see in the documentation.

Comment: OK, so to summarise the short discussion - there is no out-of-the-box solution to it in Java 5 - I should use my own implementation to it.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`. I guess you learn something new every day!

Comment: what do you mean by enclosing in "an enclosing AbstractMap instance ". Is Enclosing inferring a technical term or something in java? please guide me.

Comment: guava Maps.immutableEntry is what i was looking for

Comment: @Jesper - Its great that we can create an Entry. But there is no easy way to add an entry to a map. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441096/how-to-put-an-entry-into-a-map ? I don't want to keep extracting data from the Entry and then put it into a map. I want the map to do the extraction for me.

Comment: This Java release cadence has its headaches. 75% of the solutions on Stack Overflow don't work in my product!

Answer (score 208):

Starting from **Java 9,** there is a new utility method allowing to create an immutable entry which is [`Map#entry(Object, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-).

Here is a simple example:

```
Entry<String, String> entry = Map.entry("foo", "bar");
```

As it is immutable, calling `setValue` will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. The other limitations are the fact that it is not serializable and `null` as key or value is forbidden, if it is not acceptable for you, you will need to use [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html) or [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) instead.

**NB:** If your need is to create directly a `Map` with 0 to up to 10 (key, value) pairs, you can instead use the methods of type [`Map.of(K key1, V value1, ...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-).

Comment: It looks like Java provides basic features like this well after other languages do. Until then, we have to use clunky methods like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3110563/6648326.

Comment: Its great that we can create an Entry. But there is no easy way to add an entry to a map. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441096/how-to-put-an-entry-into-a-map ? I don't want to keep extracting data from the Entry and then put it into a map. I want the map to do the extraction for me.

Comment: @MasterJoe you can just use `Map.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2")` to add entries to a map. Or if you have an existing map: `map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())`

Answer (score 58):

Try [Maps.immutableEntry](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#immutableEntry(K,%20V)) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

This has the advantage of being compatible with Java 5 (unlike `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` which requires Java 6.)

Answer (score 36):

**Example of AbstractMap.SimpleEntry:**

```
import java.util.Map; 
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
```

**Instantiate:**

```
ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> arr = 
    new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>();
```

**Add rows:**

```
arr.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(2, 3));
arr.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(20, 30));
arr.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(2, 4));
```

**Fetch rows:**

```
System.out.println(arr.get(0).getKey());
System.out.println(arr.get(0).getValue());
System.out.println(arr.get(1).getKey());
System.out.println(arr.get(1).getValue());
System.out.println(arr.get(2).getKey());
System.out.println(arr.get(2).getValue());
```

**Should print:**

```
2
3
20
30
2
4
```

It's good for defining edges of graph structures.  Like the ones between neurons in your head.

Answer (score 20):

You could actually go with:
`Map.Entry<String, String> en= Maps.immutableEntry(key, value);`

Comment: It's useful. https://github.com/google/guava Guava is a set of core Java libraries from Google that includes new collection types (such as multimap and multiset), immutable collections, a graph library, and utilities for concurrency, I/O, hashing, caching, primitives, strings, and more! It is widely used on most Java projects within Google, and widely used by many other companies as well.

Answer (score 18):

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) of Map.Entry you will find that it is a static interface (an interface which is defined inside the Map interface an can be accessed through Map.Entry) and it has two implementations

> *All Known Implementing Classes:*
> AbstractMap.SimpleEntry, AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry

The class [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) provides 2 constructors:

> *Constructors and Description*
> **AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(K key, V value)**
> Creates an entry representing a mapping from the specified key to the
> specified value.
> **AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(Map.Entry<? extends K,? extends V> entry)**
> Creates an entry representing the same mapping as the specified entry.

An example use case:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Map.Entry e = new SimpleEntry<String, String>("Hello","World");

      System.out.println(e.getKey()+" "+e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Why `Map.Entry`? I guess something like a key-value pair is fit for the case.

Use `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` or `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`

Answer (score 9):

`org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair` implements `java.util.Map.Entry` and can also be used standalone.

Also as others mentioned Guava's `com.google.common.collect.Maps.immutableEntry(K, V)` does the trick.

I prefer `Pair` for its fluent `Pair.of(L, R)` syntax.

Comment: May I suggest `ImmutablePair` instead?

Comment: I really like the org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair class, it is awesome!

Comment: The only thing I don't like about it is that it gets serialized to left, right, key, value where left = key and right = value. Just 2 extra useless(maybe) values in the serialized string.

Answer (score 4):

I defined a generic Pair class that I use all the time. It's great. As a bonus, by defining a static factory method (Pair.create) I only have to write the type arguments half as often.

```
public class Pair<A, B> {

    private A component1;
    private B component2;

    public Pair() {
            super();
    }

    public Pair(A component1, B component2) {
            this.component1 = component1;
            this.component2 = component2;
    }

    public A fst() {
            return component1;
    }

    public void setComponent1(A component1) {
            this.component1 = component1;
    }

    public B snd() {
            return component2;
    }

    public void setComponent2(B component2) {
            this.component2 = component2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "<" + component1 + "," + component2 + ">";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result
                            + ((component1 == null) ? 0 : component1.hashCode());
            result = prime * result
                            + ((component2 == null) ? 0 : component2.hashCode());
            return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                    return true;
            if (obj == null)
                    return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                    return false;
            final Pair<?, ?> other = (Pair<?, ?>) obj;
            if (component1 == null) {
                    if (other.component1 != null)
                            return false;
            } else if (!component1.equals(other.component1))
                    return false;
            if (component2 == null) {
                    if (other.component2 != null)
                            return false;
            } else if (!component2.equals(other.component2))
                    return false;
            return true;
    }

    public static <A, B> Pair<A, B> create(A component1, B component2) {
            return new Pair<A, B>(component1, component2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted this before reading all of the other comments. Looks like you want something that's included in the standard lib...

Comment: Google Guava makes a good point of why `Pair` implementations are a bad thing. [Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/GF4QyBu0gsI)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Clojure, you have another option:

```
(defn map-entry
  [k v]
  (clojure.lang.MapEntry/create k v))
```