# List of entries, how to add a new Entry?

Tags: java

In Java, I am implementing this:

```
List<Entry<String, Integer>> listObjects = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>();
```

but how can I add a new Entry?

as it does not work with: `listObjects.add(new Entry<"abc", 1>());`

thanks in advance.

Comment: All questions should have expected behaviour _and_ actual behaviour (the error generated in your case). What is javac/Eclipse/NetBeans  (or the JRE if it's a runtime thing) saying the actual problem is?

Comment: can you give a "concise" answer?

Comment: what does "does not work" actually mean?

Comment: I can not create a new Entry object!

Comment: To anyone having the same question, be sure to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110547/java-how-to-create-new-entry-key-value/3110563#3110563) to the [_How to create a new Entry (key, value)_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110547/java-how-to-create-new-entry-key-value) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean [`Map.Entry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)? That is an interface (so you can't instantiate without an implementation class, you can [learn about interfaces in the Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)). `Entry` instances are usually only created by [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementations and only exposed through [`Map.entrySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29)

Of course, since it's an interface you could add your own implementation, something like this:

```
public class MyEntry<K, V> implements Entry<K, V> {
    private final K key;
    private V value;
    public MyEntry(final K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public MyEntry(final K key, final V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public V setValue(final V value) {
        final V oldValue = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        return oldValue;
    }
}
```

That way you could do `listObjects.add(new MyEntry<String,Integer>("abc", 1))`

But that doesn't really make sense outside of a map context.

Comment: the generics misuse was so obvoius I did not think about that :) deleting my answer

Answer (score 13):

I know it's a pretty older thread but you can do it as follows:

```
listObjects.add(new java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>("abc", 1));
```

It might help someone like me, who was trying to do this recently!

I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 4):

`Entry` is a *parametized* class and you need to create instances of `Entry` with a constructor (typical way).

Without knowing the implementation of `Entry`: this could already work (at least it shows how it usually works):

```
// create a list
List<Entry<String, Integer>> listObjects = 
               new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>()

// create an instance of Entry
Entry<String, Integer> entry = new Entry<String, Integer>("abc", 1);

// add the instance of Entry to the list
listObjects.add(entry);
```

---

With `Map.Entry` it is somewhat different (OP just mentioned, that `Entry` is `Map.Entry` in Fact. We can't create `Map.Entry` instances, we usually get them from an existing map:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = getMapFromSomewhere();
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> listObjects = 
               new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:map.entrySet())
    listObjects.add(entry);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to use a ready made implementation of `Entry` would be [Guava's Immutable Entry](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#immutableEntry%28K,%20V%29)
Something like this `listObjects.add(Maps.immutableEntry("abc",1));`

Comment: Guava doesn't work with null elements. It's not useful in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `listObjects.add(new Entry<String, Integer>("abc", 1));`? The generics specify the type (`String`, `Integer`), not the values (`abc`, `1`).

*Edit* - Note that it was later added that the `Entry` is in fact `Map.Entry`, so you need to create an implementation of `Map.Entry` that you later instantiate, exactly as the chosen answer explains.

Comment: listObjects.add(new Entry<String, Integer>("abc", 1)); also does work.  Thanks!

Comment: @stifin you are right, however the original question did not mention `Map.Entry`; OP clarified it later, once the answers were already given; of course in that case you must implement `Map.Entry` and instantiate that