# java key/value pair object, that isn't an array/map

Tags: java, object, hashmap, key-value

I want a key value pair object. Just two strings

so `Object<String, String>`

is there an existing object in java to facilitate this before I reinvent the wheel?

The only reason I didn't immediately gravitate to Hash/Map this time is because that one object is made to store multiple key/value pairs. Is there one designed to hold just a single key/value pair, that I can turn into an array if I feel inclined to do so?

Comment: Looks like a standard implementation of a Tuple...

Comment: There is no built in object to support this like `Pair` in C++, but it would be relatively easy to create one.

Comment: already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java

Comment: "that I can turn into an array if I feel inclined to do so?" -- can you clarify? Do you want `Pair( str1, str2 ).toArray() --> [str1, str2]` do you actually want a single-entry map?

Comment: @CQM Just wondering whether you actually want `Collections.singletonMap(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create your own.  This is done (AFAIK) to facilitate a better semantic meaning from the class name, than a general `Pair<>` or `KeyValuePair<>` would

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java/156685#156685 for some more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

and an implementation from SO [Java - How to create new Entry (key, value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110547/java-how-to-create-new-entry-key-value)

Comment: That class sort of implies that this class will be used as a part of something, with a bunch of these `Entry` objects. The OP just wants a stand alone object that can hold two things.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Linked-List of Pair.

Basic structure

(0) --> <-- ((0)(Pair < 1, "Stud" >)(2)) --> <-- (1)(Pair < 2, "Sexy" >)(3)....

Where each Node in the structure is (prev. < K,V >, this < K,V >, next < K,V >)
Allows for duplicated keys however...

Head & Tail are null if the Linked-List is empty;