# How to put/get values into/from Nested HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, nested

I want to create a nested HashMap that will take two keys of type float and give out value of type Integer.

```
 public static HashMap<Float, HashMap<Float, Integer>> hashX = new HashMap<Float,HashMap<Float, Integer>>();
```

Is there a simple method of putting/getting the values like an ordinary HashMap i.e.

```
  hashX.put(key, value);
  hashX.get(key);
```

or is it a more complicated method that must be used? 
I have searched around the web for a solution but am finding it tough to find a solution that applies to me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should use the `Map` interface like this `Map<Float, HashMap<Float, Integer>>` in your type declaration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Map<Float, Map<Float, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(.0F, new HashMap(){{put(.0F,0);}});
map.put(.1F, new HashMap(){{put(.1F,1);}});

map.get(.0F).get(.0F);
```

Comment: And the infamous instance initializer block appears. :)

Comment: That's a `NullPointerException`, because `map.get(0)` will return `null`

Comment: @isvforall thanks, is there anyway around using HashMap<>(), i'm using Android and I can't use level 1.7 as Android requires 5.0

Comment: @user1927105 Unfortunately, only `HashMap<Float, Map<Float, Integer>>();`

Comment: @AdamArold why infamous?

Comment: @JanacMeena this is subjective, but most people I know don't like it (including me) because it makes the code harder to read and reason about.

Answer (score 5):

You have to `get()` the nested map out of the outer map and call can call `put()` and `get()` on it

```
float x = 1.0F;
HashMap<Float, Integer> innerMap = hashX.get(x);
if (innerMap == null) {
    hashX.put(x, innerMap = new HashMap<>()); // Java version >= 1.7
}
innerMap.put(2.0F, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper class with a method like this:

```
public class MyWrapper {
    private Map<Float, Map<Float, Integer>> hashX;
    // ...
    public void doublePut(Float one, Float two, Integer value) {
        if (hashX.get(one) == null) {
            hashX.put(one, new HashMap<Float, Integer>());
        }
      hashX.get(one).put(two, value);
    }
}
```

Please note that you should use interfaces instead of concrete implementations when you declare your fields. For example it would make easier to refactor `HashMap` into `ConcurrentHashMap` if the need arises.

Comment: Why don't you save the reference to the new map, to avoid the following lookup operation, like you saw in my answer?

Comment: Well this looked somewhat a more idiomatic way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
HashMap<Float, Integer> h1 = new HashMap<Float, Integer>();
h1.put(1.0f,new Integer(1));
HashMap<Float, Integer> h2 = new HashMap<Float, Integer>();
h2.put(3.0f,new Integer(3));

hashX.put(1.0f, h1);
hashX.put(1.0f, h1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static <K0, K1, V> void put(Map<K0, Map<K1, V>> map, K0 k0, K1 k1, V value) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(k0, x -> new HashMap<>()).put(k1, value);
}

static <K0, K1, V> V get(Map<K0, Map<K1, V>> map, K0 k0, K1 k1) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(k0)).map(s -> s.get(k1)).orElse(null);
}
```

and

```
Map<Float, Map<Float, Float>> map = new HashMap<>();
put(map, 1F, 2F, 3F);
put(map, 4F, 5F, 6F);
System.out.println(map);
```

output:

```
{4.0={5.0=6.0}, 1.0={2.0=3.0}}
```

Or simply

```
Map<Float, Map<Float, Float>> map = Map.of(
    1F, Map.of(2F, 3F),
    4F, Map.of(5F, 6F));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a nested HashMap that will take two keys of type float and give out value of type Integer.

You don't *need* a nested Map for that. If you want to lookup using a composite key, it is better to declare your map to be as such. There isn't a good `Pair` class in JFK, but you ca use `Map.Entry`, which is somewhat inconvenient to use but works:

```
Map<Map<Float, Float>, Integer> map = new ....
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3110563/18573 for creating `Map.Entry` instances

Answer (score -3):

```java
package com.Collection;

import java.util.*;

public class India {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set s = new TreeSet();
        s.add("Barshi");
        s.add("Pandharpur");
        s.add("Kurduwadi");
        s.add("Vairag");
        Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,TreeSet>>> map =               
                Map.of("India", Map.of("Maharashtra", Map.of("Solapur", new TreeSet(s))));
                
        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println(map.get("India").get("Maharashtra").get("Solapur").contains("Barshi"));
    }

}
```