# Nested String HashMaps

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I know I have the option to make a POJO object to store this. However, I am trying to do it in a nested HashMap. Whenever I do the following I am getting Type Safety Warnings.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
map.put("fund_cde", new HashMap(){{put("ABC", "ABC is not valid message.");}});
```

If I set the nested HashMaps type like so:

```
map.put("fund_cde", new HashMap<String, String>(){{put("ABC", "ABC is not valid message");}});
```

I end up with this warning instead:

The serializable class  does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long

Any advice on correct way to do this? 
I had a look at [How to put/get values into/from Nested HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582596/how-to-put-get-values-into-from-nested-hashmap) but I'm still not understanding it.

Thanks!

Comment: Just parameterize your `HashMap` in your first example. And add elements on multiple lines. These anonymous classes are messy and not easily readable.

Comment: The second is correct. Serializability is a separate issue.

Comment: ^^ There is nothing wrong with the code snippet you have posted (the second version). The error you are now receiving is coming from code you aren't showing us (writing a simple two line test of the code you show would tell you that).

Comment: Thanks - Surely I'm not going to add serial ID for each. (Don't know enough about serializability though.) Will take a look into it again. Least my hashmap is right.

Comment: Just make all the maps <String,Object> and cast as required on retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to achieve this if you like you can use because I also tried in different manner that also give warning.You can use this

```
Map<String,String> map1=new HashMap<String,String>();
    map1.put("ABC", "XYZ");
    Map<String ,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("axz", map1);
```

Comment: @Bitzal I hope it will help you .plz tell me if you find it useful

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do away with the warning. Either include a version id like:

```
map.put("fund_cde", new HashMap(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        {put("ABC", "ABC is not valid message.");}
});
```

or add the @SuppressWarnings("serial") annotation to the method. If you use an IDE like eclipse it can offer you these options as auto fixes.

Comment: Um, this isn't the issue. `Hashmap` already implements `Serializable` and has a `serialVersionUID` - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#1023

Comment: Yes HashMap does but the Anonymous Class does not. You can confirm this by trying to get:

    new HashMap<String, String>() {{System.out.println(serialVersionUID);}}

to compile.

Comment: And in contrast: new HashMap<String, String>() {private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; {System.out.println(serialVersionUID);}} compiles just fine.

Comment: Also Bitzal states in the question that the warning is "The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long"