# How to mock the return value of a Map?

Tags: java, mockito

I have code that looks like so:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Action> entry : availableActions.entrySet()) {
  ...
}
```

I've tried to mock it like this:

```
Map mockAvailableActions = mock(Map.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
mockAvailableActions.put(new Integer(1), mockAction);
```

I would think that would be enough. But entrySet is empty. So I added this:

```
when(mockAvailableActions.entrySet().iterator()).thenReturn(mockIterator);
when(mockIterator.next()).thenReturn(mockAction);
```

Still entrySet is empty. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why not just do this:

```
Map.Entry<Integer, Action> entrySet = <whatever you want it to return>
Map mockAvailableActions = mock(Map.class);
when(mockAvailableActions.entrySet()).thenReturn(entrySet);
```

Also consider whether you actually need a mock Map at all, wouldn't a real one do the job? Mocks are usually used to replace other pieces of your code which you don't want to be involved in your unit test, a Map is part of the core Java language and isn't usually mocked out.

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought. But what would "Map.Entry<Integer, Action> entrySet =" look like? Entry can't be instantiated, so I would I define the variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110547/java-how-to-create-new-entry-key-value

Comment: You were right Codebox - this answer was not to mock the Map at all.