# Java Map.Entry and TreeSet

Tags: java, dictionary, treeset

I've created a TreeSet and I'm trying to add a Map.Entry to it. But this will not compile. What am I doing wrong?

```
TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> treeSet = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>();

treeSet.add( Map.Entry<String, Integer>("Text string...", 123) );
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `TreeMap`?

Comment: I think it would be better to use your own object, implementing your own `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: This is a school assignment, just follow the instructions. I don't know really know Java yet and I'm stuck.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the instructions. If you'll explain what you're trying to do, you may be able to get useful help.

Comment: What is the error shown when you try to compile?

Comment: I'm trying to add value pairs (String and Integer) into a TreeSet and sort it. The interface I must follow looks like this: public TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> test_1(...);

Comment: You'll be way better by creating your own class that has this pair data and implement `Comparable` interface instead of trying to reuse `Map.Entry<K, V>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to instantiate a `Map.Entry`. I guess you can simply use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Even though, if you want that, you can instantiate [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) like this:

```
Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry =
    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>("exmpleString", 42);
```

Note that [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is an interface. Oh! And of course, as rightly specified in comments by @Louis, `Map.Entry` doesn't implement a `Comparable`, so you won't be able to add it to `TreeSet`.

You can however create your own implementation of this interface, make that implement `Comparable<Map.Entry<K, V>>`, and use that instead.

---

But as I said, you can use a `TreeMap`, and use its [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#entrySet%28%29) method which will give you a `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`:

```
SortedMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();
```

Comment: The only downside of this answer is the usage of `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

Comment: `Map.Entry` doesn't implement `Comparable`, so you can't add a `Map.Entry` to a `TreeSet` without specifying a `Comparator`.

Comment: I must use TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>, so if I do something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110547/java-how-to-create-new-entry-key-value it should work?

Comment: No, that's still not enough; you must implement a `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`.  Frankly, it's a ridiculous requirement that you have to use a `TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`.

Comment: @user1121487 Yes you can create your own implementation, and also implement the `Comparable` interface for that class. Then you can use it in `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html:

> A map entry (key-value pair). The Map.entrySet method returns a
>   collection-view of the map, whose elements are of this class. The only
>   way to obtain a reference to a map entry is from the iterator of this
>   collection-view. These Map.Entry objects are valid only for the
>   duration of the iteration; more formally, the behavior of a map entry
>   is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was
>   returned by the iterator, except through the setValue operation on the
>   map entry.

In other words - you can't do what you're trying to do.  While as Rohit Jain pointed out you can do something similar with `AstractMap.simpleEntry(..)`, it seems to me that there are very few use cases in this world where that would be a "good" solution.

Instead, if you're wanting to store key/value pairs in a `TreeSet` you'll need to create your own Object.  That said - why not just use a `TreeMap` or similar?

Comment: I've been given this interface: public TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> test_1(...); Since it's a TreeSet including Map.Entry value pairs, it must be achievable?