# Transform and filter a Java Map with streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a Java Map that I'd like to transform and filter. As a trivial example, suppose I want to convert all values to Integers then remove the odd entries.

```
Map<String, String> input = new HashMap<>();
input.put("a", "1234");
input.put("b", "2345");
input.put("c", "3456");
input.put("d", "4567");

Map<String, Integer> output = input.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getValue())
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() % 2 == 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));


System.out.println(output.toString());
```

This is correct and yields: `{a=1234, c=3456}`

However, I can't help but wonder if there's a way to avoid calling `.entrySet().stream()` twice.

Is there a way I can perform both transform and filter operations and call  `.collect()` only once at the end?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Based on javadoc "A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may throw IllegalStateException if it detects that the stream is being reused."

Comment: @Namban That's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, you can map each entry to another temporary entry that will hold the key and the parsed integer value. Then you can filter each entry based on their value.

```
Map<String, Integer> output =
    input.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), Integer.valueOf(e.getValue())))
         .filter(e -> e.getValue() % 2 == 0)
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
             Map.Entry::getKey,
             Map.Entry::getValue
         ));
```

Note that I used `Integer.valueOf` instead of `parseInt` since we actually want a boxed `int`.

---

If you have the luxury to use the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library, you can do it quite simply:

```
Map<String, Integer> output =
    EntryStream.of(input).mapValues(Integer::valueOf).filterValues(v -> v % 2 == 0).toMap();
```

Comment: Though this is one possible hacky way to do, I feel like we are sacrificing performance + readability for few lines of code, isn't it?

Comment: @Nambari I don't see why it is that "hacky". It's just a map filter. If it's the explicit use of `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`, you can create another `Pair` but I feel it is appropriate here since we're dealing with maps already.

Comment: I used "hacky" just because of "temporary entry" we are tracking, may not be correct term. I liked StreamEx solution.

Comment: @Nambari, note that StreamEx does the same thing internally, it's just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: @TagirValeev: Yes, I know.When API doesn't support, all these libraries just does the sytactic sugar.

Comment: In the map method that you used, what if we have multiple lines of logic in there and then we return a new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry ? This is throwing me a Null Pointer exception during Collect. Not sure why? Please help

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52426752/744133 for different use of a `Map.Entry`

Answer (score 19):

One way to solve the problem with much lesser overhead is to move the mapping and filtering down to the collector.

```
Map<String, Integer> output = input.entrySet().stream().collect(
    HashMap::new,
    (map,e)->{ int i=Integer.parseInt(e.getValue()); if(i%2==0) map.put(e.getKey(), i); },
    Map::putAll);
```

This does not require the creation of intermediate `Map.Entry` instances and even better, will postpone the boxing of `int` values to the point when the values are actually added to the `Map`, which implies that values rejected by the filter are not boxed at all.

Compared to what `Collectors.toMap(…)` does, the operation is also simplified by using `Map.put` rather than `Map.merge` as we know beforehand that we don’t have to handle key collisions here.

However, as long as you don’t want to utilize parallel execution you may also consider the ordinary loop

```
HashMap<String,Integer> output=new HashMap<>();
for(Map.Entry<String, String> e: input.entrySet()) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(e.getValue());
    if(i%2==0) output.put(e.getKey(), i);
}
```

or the internal iteration variant:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> output=new HashMap<>();
input.forEach((k,v)->{ int i = Integer.parseInt(v); if(i%2==0) output.put(k, i); });
```

the latter being quite compact and at least on par with all other variants regarding single threaded performance.

Comment: I upvoted for your recommendation of a plain loop.  Just because you can use streams doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom: yeah, the good old `for` loop is still alive. Though in the case of maps, I like to use the `Map.forEach` method for smaller loops just because `(k,v)->` is much nicer than declaring a `Map.Entry<PossiblyLongKeyType,PossiblyLongValueType>` variable and possibly another two variables for the actual key and value…

Answer (score 6):

[Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html)'s your friend:

```
Map<String, Integer> output = Maps.filterValues(Maps.transformValues(input, Integer::valueOf), i -> i % 2 == 0);
```

Keep in mind that `output` is a transformed, filtered *view* of `input`. You'll need to make a copy if you want to operate on them independently.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`Stream.collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method to transform the entries and conditionally accumulate them:

```
Map<String, Integer> even = input.entrySet().stream().collect(
    HashMap::new,
    (m, e) -> Optional.ofNullable(e)
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
            .ifPresent(i -> m.put(e.getKey(), i)),
    Map::putAll);

System.out.println(even); // {a=1234, c=3456}
```

Here, inside the accumulator, I'm using `Optional` methods to apply both the transformation and the predicate, and, if the optional value is still present, I'm adding it to the map being collected.

Comment: Very close to [my first variant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35490546/2711488)  but I don’t think that the use of `Optional` is a win here…

Comment: @Holger it's just to keep everything in one line. Anyways, I hadn't seen your answer. The win (if we become very subtle), might be that `Optional.ofNullable()` allows for null keys.

Comment: We were writing at the same time. The `Optional` chain actually isn’t one line (or a very large one) but a single expression. But starting with a certain expression size, the two curly braces needed for a statement lambda do not appear that costly anymore…

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to remove the values you don't want from the transformed `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> output = input.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getValue()),
                (a, b) -> { throw new AssertionError(); },
                HashMap::new
         ));
output.values().removeIf(v -> v % 2 != 0);
```

This assumes you want a mutable `Map` as the result, if not you can probably create an immutable one from `output`.

---

If you are transforming the values into the same type and want to modify the `Map` in place this could be alot shorter with [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
input.replaceAll((k, v) -> v + " example");
input.values().removeIf(v -> v.length() > 10);
```

This also assumes `input` is mutable.

---

I don't recommend doing this because It will not work for all valid `Map` implementations and may stop working for `HashMap` in the future, but you can currently use `replaceAll` and cast a `HashMap` to change the type of the values:

```
((Map)input).replaceAll((k, v) -> Integer.parseInt((String)v));
Map<String, Integer> output = (Map)input;
output.values().removeIf(v -> v % 2 != 0);
```

This will also give you type safety warnings and if you try to retrieve a value from the `Map` through a reference of the old type like this:

```
String ex = input.get("a");
```

It will throw a `ClassCastException`.

---

You could move the first transform part into a method to avoid the boilerplate if you expect to use it alot:

```
public static <K, VO, VN, M extends Map<K, VN>> M transformValues(
        Map<? extends K, ? extends VO> old, 
        Function<? super VO, ? extends VN> f, 
        Supplier<? extends M> mapFactory){
    return old.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Entry::getKey, 
            e -> f.apply(e.getValue()), 
            (a, b) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate keys for values " + a + " " + b); },
            mapFactory));
}
```

And use it like this:

```
    Map<String, Integer> output = transformValues(input, Integer::parseInt, HashMap::new);
    output.values().removeIf(v -> v % 2 != 0);
```

Note that the duplicate key exception can be thrown if, for example, the `old` `Map` is an `IdentityHashMap` and the `mapFactory` creates a `HashMap`.

Comment: Your `"Duplicate keys " + a + " " + b` message is misleading: `a` and `b` are actually values, not keys.

Comment: @TagirValeev yes, I noticed that, but it's the same way it's done in `Collectors` for the two argument version of `toMap` and changing it to what I had considered would put a scrollbar on the code box so I decided to leave it. I'll change it now since you also think it is misleading.

Comment: Yes, this is known problem which is already fixed in [Java-9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892) (but not backported to Java-8). Java-9 displays colliding key as well as both values in the exception message.

Comment: The funny thing about your unsafe hack is that the `groupingBy` collector does something similar behind the scenes which can come at a big surprise when you use a supplier creating map implementations enforcing type safety, e.g. `()->Collections.checkedMap(new HashMap<>(), …)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is code by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Map<String, String> input = N.asMap("a", "1234", "b", "2345", "c", "3456", "d", "4567");

Map<String, Integer> output = Stream.of(input)
                          .groupBy(e -> e.getKey(), e -> N.asInt(e.getValue()))
                          .filter(e -> e.getValue() % 2 == 0)
                          .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue);

N.println(output.toString());
```

Declaration： I'm the developer of abacus-common.