# How to put an Entry into a Map?

Tags: java, dictionary

Is there any way that I can put a whole `Entry` object to a `Map` object like:

```
map.put(entry);
```

instead of passing a key-value pair like:

```
map.put(key,value);
```

Comment: Is there a reason `map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())` is unsatisfactory?

Comment: Because `map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())` is redundant and can be
reduced to just `map.put(entry)` which is more concise and readable. In my
opinion also, there should be a `V put(Entry<K,V> entry)` method in the 
`Map` interface of `java.util` package.

Comment: _When_ would you need such a method -- what would be the use case? I think it's not in the API, because [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: I'm with Mick here... I think the reason it isn't in the API is that it wasn't envisioned as being something particularly useful.  API designers can't predict everything every programmer may want in every situation and add stuff to the API for it.  Anyway, if you're doing this a lot, you could write your own helper method that takes an `Entry` parameter; then you could make concise and readable calls to your own helper method.

Comment: By making this question I just tried to be helpful on how someone could just do map.put(entry). Something that is not supported by the Java Standard libraries, because as @ajb and MickMnemonic said maybe it is not useful. In my opinion, although the above method might be useless, the question is not that useless so that it worths downvoting.

Comment: @pgmank, I understand your point, and someone might find your solution useful. You might have gotten downvoted because someone thought the question is too broad. However, I do think that for any code to be useful, there would need to be a particular problem that the code solves. Each time I have personally been working with map entries, it has happened in the context of iterating over the entry set and involved processing these entries somehow. But I've never needed to put entries "as is" into another map. So I was just curious about the intended use here.

Comment: One of the reasons is that we can use other collections such as Arraylists to just add/put objects. But in that case, we need to check the type before using the objects. Actually, it is better to have a key when the collection is designed to store different objects types and not to have it when we know we have one type of object in the collection.

Comment: How exactly are you going to get an `Entry` that isn't already in the `Map`?

Comment: @user207421 `Map.Entry<K,V> entry = Map.entry(key, value);` there is even a method in the API to create entries.

Comment: @ajb - Why do we have an Entry interface to begin with ? One of the reasons I can think of is to put it into Map. If yes, then why not provide a simple method to do that ? Here is a sample use case. Say you get an Entry expressed as a String like this Character =>CharacterCount). You convert the String into an Entry which is then returned to a method that stores character counts for all characters in a string.

Comment: @ajb - I think its mainly a matter of convenience to have utility methods like map.put(entry). Java is often late to understand this which is why I think they often introduce things like Lombok, lambdas well after other languages have introduced them.

Comment: @MasterJoe2 - A primary reason I can think of for having `Entry` is so that you can use it in a `for` statement: `for ((Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) { ... }`.  Unlike some languages, Java syntax doesn't provide a way to write a `for` that assigns to two or more variables, so it needed a type that would represent both the key and value.  Without `Entry`, doing this kind of operation on each map entry would be more cumbersome (without `forEach` which wasn't added until Java 8).  I think that's a much greater need than `put`, which you can write pretty easily.

Comment: @ajb - thanks. but, its nice to have all the utility code in built so that we can focus on the app logic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have searched on the Map interface methods but there is no method that
takes an entry and puts it in the map. Therefore I have implemented it
by myself using a little bit of inheritance and Java 8 interfaces.

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Maps {

    // Test method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 = newEntry("Key1", "Value1");
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 = newEntry("Key2", "Value2");

        System.out.println("HashMap");
        MyMap<String, String> hashMap = new MyHashMap<>();
        hashMap.put(entry1);
        hashMap.put(entry2);

        for (String key : hashMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + " = " + hashMap.get(key));
        }

        System.out.println("\nTreeMap");
        MyMap<String, String> treeMap = new MyTreeMap<>();
        treeMap.put(entry1);
        treeMap.put(entry2);


        for (String key : treeMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + " = " + treeMap.get(key));
        }
    }


    /**
     * Creates a new Entry object given a key-value pair.
     * This is just a helper method for concisely creating a new Entry.
     * @param key   key of the entry
     * @param value value of the entry
     * 
     * @return  the Entry object containing the given key-value pair
     */
    private static <K,V> Map.Entry<K,V> newEntry(K key, V value) {
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value);
    }

    /**
     * An enhanced Map interface.
     */
    public static interface MyMap<K,V> extends Map<K,V> {

        /**
         * Puts a whole entry containing a key-value pair to the map.
         * @param entry 
         */
        public default V put(Entry<K,V> entry) {
            return put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    /**
     * An enhanced HashMap class.
     */
    public static class MyHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> implements MyMap<K,V> {}

    /**
     * An enhanced TreeMap class.
     */
    public static class MyTreeMap<K,V> extends TreeMap<K,V> implements MyMap<K,V> {}
}
```

The `MyMap` interface is just an interface that extends the `Map` interface
by adding one more method, the `public default V put(Entry<K,V> entry)`. 
Apart from just defining the method, a default implementation is coded 
too. Doing that, we can now add this method to any class that implements 
the `Map` interface just by defining a new class that implements the 
`MyMap` interface and extending the map implementation class of our choice. All 
of that in one line! This is demonstrated in the bottom of the code above where two 
classes are created each extending the HashMap and the TreeMap 
implementations.

Comment: Is all this really 'more concise and readable' tan `map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())`?

Comment: The above is a workaround for being able to do `map.put(entry)`, (which is far more concise than `map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())`), because so far, there is no such method implemented in Java SE. If Java engineers were to implement such feature [they would have to insert just one method in the `Map` interface, as I have commented in my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441096/how-to-put-an-entry-into-a-map#comment66204778_39441096).

Comment: Workarounds always tend to be more lengthy than the straightforward solution. But in this case the straightforward solution does not depend on me but on the Java engineers. The purpose of my answer was to demonstrate that, one can implement such feature even if its not inherent in the language itself, with a few lines of code and without importing any new libraries. Notice that most of the code in my answer is occupied by the `main()` method which is used only for testing/demonstration. If we exclude the comments, its just 14 lines of code including the import statements.

Comment: If it were for the Java engineers to implement this feature it would need just 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 7):

To instantiate a Map with Entries (in the same way as you can do `Arrays.asList(T... a)` or `Sets.newHashSet(T... a)` in Google Guava library, I found this:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapWithEntries {

    private static final Map.Entry<String, String> ENTRY_1 = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("A", "Hello");
    private static final Map.Entry<String, String> ENTRY_2 = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("B", "World");

    private static final Map<String, String> MAP_WITH_ENTRIES = Map.ofEntries(ENTRY_1, ENTRY_2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Guava's `ImmutableMap.Builder` [takes entries directly](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html#put(java.util.Map.Entry)).

Obviously that doesn't directly modify an existing `Map`, but it might well scratch the same itch.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the putAll method. First filter out the required entries from the source map and pass them in putAll method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in the comments below, the doc explicitly states that add and addAll are not supported so this is wrong.

```
    Map<Integer, String> map;
    Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry;
     ...
    map.entrySet().add(entry);
    map.entrySet().addAll(List.of(entry));
```

Comment: From the [docs of Map.entrySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) - `It does not support the add or addAll operations.` This will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score -6):

Solution if you're using Java Platform SE 8:

SimpleEntry and SimpleImmutableEntry classes implement interface
     Map.Entry

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry;

List<Map.Entry<K, V>> map = new ArrayList<>(); 
map.add(new SimpleEntry<K,V>(key,value));
map.add(new SimpleImmutableEntry<K,V>(key,value)); // constructs immutable entries for thread-safe operation
```

Comment: But `map` is actually a List, not a `java.util.Map`. The whole point of using a map is to be able to do `map.get(someKey)` and with this you need to scan the entire list to find which entry has its key equal to `someKey` and then return the value. Thus reinventing the wheel, and doing it badly, for maps are optimised for exactly those operations.