# Mocking and Handling Map.Entry when it is returned from a method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, collections

Summary: I am confused about how to handle a single "Map.Entry" when returned from a method call.  In my specific case, I need to mock this (using mockito presently) but my question is as much about how to deal with "Map.Entry" as a single unit than it is about mocking it...  Help with both would be greatly appreciated.

============================

I have a method like the following.  I need to create a matching entity (a Map.Entry I assume) for the mock to return when the method is called. I don't know how to create a single Map.Entry.  I've traced calls all the way back to the sql call to the db, but can only find a point where the returned Object is cast to a Map.Entry.

No indication of how to build such a thing.  I need help with how to build a single "Map.Entry" that can be returned by the mock.

```
 public Map.Entry<Date,Boolean> getLastModified(SomeClass someClass)
    throws Exception
    {
        return clusterViewDataProvider.getClusterModified(someClass);
    }
```

Here is a line that would create the mocked object for me. For simplicity, assume that the method above is in the "Foo" class.

```
Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);
```

Then I would need something like this to say that when the method is called (as a mock) it should return the "Map.Entry" that I need to build.

```
when(foo.getLastModifiedGid(any())).thenReturn(the Map.Entry I don't know how to make yet);
```

Lastly, I need to assert something testable about the Map.Entry that is returned.  I'm fine to check the key and value in the assert - nothing fancier than that is required - again, I'm not sure how I'd access this as a single Map.Entry...

```
assertTrue(The Key == SomeDate)
assertTrue(The Value == True)
```

If I've been unclear on anything, please comment and I will clarify.  Gratzi.

Comment: Go to the javadoc of Map.Entry: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html. Look at the list f implementing classes. Choose the one you prefer. Create an instance of that class.

Comment: How do I place a Map.Entry into a HashMap?  How do I accept the return value of that method?  It doesn't matter which instance of the implementing class I use probably, but I'm unclear on what the code would look like and reading the docs isn't super useful in this case.  A code sample would be appreciated.  This link suggests it's not straightforward... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441096/how-to-put-an-entry-into-a-map

Comment: `when(foo.getLastModifiedGid(any())).thenReturn(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(someKey, someValue))`

Comment: @JBNizet Many thanks!

Comment: I also found this approach to create my "object to be returned by a mock"  Map.Entry me = new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry <>(new Date(), Boolean.TRUE);

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to create your own `Map.Entry` implementation. You can use one of the existing implementations like [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html):

```
Date date = new Date();
boolean value = true;

Map.Entry<Date, Boolean> entry =  new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(date, value);
when(foo.getLastModifiedGid(any())).thenReturn(entry);
```

or [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html) :

```
Map.Entry<Date, Boolean> entry =  new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(date, value);
```

As a side note, date classes from `java.util` are obesolete and classes from `java.time` should be used for Java 8+. Specifically, `java.util.Date` is replaced by [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

Comment: Good point about *java.time*. And even for Java 6 & Java 7, it is better to use the back-port library, [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), than to use the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Date`.

Comment: Agreed - I'm mocking legacy code for unit tests that should have been written long ago - thus the use of Date...

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own entry

```
class DummyEntry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {

        K key;
        V value;

        public DummyEntry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public V setValue(V value) {
            this.value = value;
            return value;
        }
    }
```

And then return it in your mock.

```
when(foo.getLastModifiedGid(any())).thenReturn(new DummyEntry(...))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Building your own custom Entry class requires a lot of additional code implementation solely for the case of testing**.

This should be a red flag for designing tests, as it is likely that you're making the problem much more complicated than it needs to be.

Instead, why not create an actual map and have the map do the work?

```
    //define your expected response element
    Date foo = ...;
    Boolean bar = ...;

    //instantiate map
    Map<Date,Boolean> dummyMap = new HashMap<>();
    dummyMap.put(foo, bar);

    //fetch an actual working copy from a functional map
    Map.Entry<Date, Boolean> baz = dummyMap.entrySet().stream().findFirst().get();

    //mock away
    when(foo.getLastModifiedGid(any())).thenReturn(baz);
```

I am somewhat confused as to why you'd assert something regarding the Entry itself. If you define it, it should be yours. If your method under test changes it, test the results of that, and not the canned object you provided it.

Comment: I agree on the matter of testing the Entry - in this case I'm mocking a "hit" on a database - I don't want to hit the DB in a Unit test, as I'm sure you'd agree...  This "hit" to the DB is several levels deep and I guess what I'm doing is "testing" that nothing in between mutates what this deep-level call returns...  Sometimes I feel that writing tests like this is not the best use of my time, but corporate rules mandate high code coverage - and so I write them...