# Create new Map.Entry - seems harder than it needs to be

Tags: java, hashmap, java-11

I have these two methods:

```
 @Override
  public void done(E e, Map.Entry<String, T> m) {

  }

  @Override
  public void done(E e, String k, T v) {
     this.done(e, null);
  }
```

instead of passing null, how can I create a new Map.Entry? I tried:

```
this.done(e, Map.of(k,v));
```

but that creates a Map not a Map.Entry.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110547/java-how-to-create-new-entry-key-value

Comment: `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, T>("myKey", value)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Java 9+, you can use [`Map.entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) as:

```
static <E, T> void done(E e, Map.Entry<String, T> m) {
     // do something
}

// using immutable entry
static <E, T> void done(E e, String k, T v) {
    done(e, Map.entry(k, v));
}

// using mutable entry 
static <E, T> void done(E e, String k, T v) {
    done(e, new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(k, v));
}
```

Comment: Nice (+1). It should be noted though, that `Map.entry(k, v)` will return an immutable entry. If changes are required, I guess we still need to use the good old `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

Comment: @Kartik ofcourse, thanks updated.

Comment: @Kartik the constraints on `Map.entry` are the  same as for `Map.of` (e.g. not only immutable but also disallowing `null`), which the OP seems to already know.