# Map.entry(...) is undefined for type Map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I was messing around with Java and hashmaps on a Computer at School.

I was able to instantiate an `Entry` of type `String, Integer` on the fly. Then add it to an `ArrayList` of `Entrie`s. I emailed this code to myself for later.

However on my home computer and my laptop, it wont let me. Same exact code says

> The method `entry(string,int)` is undefined for type `Map`

The code is:

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = Map.entry(largest, maxCount);
```

---

I think this has something to do with the fact that `Map.Entry` is an interface?

As google results seem to say you have to make your own `Entry` class to do this? But did that change in newer versions of Java? Why was I able to execute this code just fine earlier?

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

Lookup the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) of this method. It says:

> **Since: 9**

Which means that this method was added in Java 9.

So your machine at home likely did not have Java 9 or newer.

---

### Upgrade

Run `java -version` and `javac -version` in your CMD to verify your version. Then install a more recent Java (for example from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk13&jvmVariant=hotspot)).

---

### Pre Java 9

In case you are searching for a solution that works without Java 9, you can use something like:

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>(largest, maxCount);
```

As explained in more detail here: [Java - How to create new Entry (key, value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110547/java-how-to-create-new-entry-key-value)

You said:

> As google results seem to say you have to make your own Entry class to do this?

That is true for versions before Java 6. The mentioned class `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` was added in Java 6 and can be (ab)used for this purpose. Before that, you would have to create your own implementation.

---

### OOP

Another option, which might arguably be better, could be to create your own little class to hold that data and then give it a proper name.

For example, instead of having a `Map.Entry<String, Integer>` that stores a person by his `String name` and `int age`, why not create a `Person` class directly:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    // Constructor and getters, ...
}
```

Is much more readable, easier to maintain and extend.