# Combine filter and map in Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Suppose you have a list of users, which realistically would come from a database repository.

```
User alice = new User(1, "alice", "9akDj18xA");
User bob = new User(2, "bob", "mLih41nZxx");
User carol = new User(3, "carol", "tFxn2Ad70");

List<User> users = List.of(alice, bob, carol);
```

Each user has an id, a name, and a key that can be used to access third party services.

```
class User {
    int id;
    String name;
    String consentKey;

    public User(int id, String name, String consentKey) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.consentKey = consentKey;
    }
  }
```

Sometimes the third party service returns data - a medical record - that looks like this.

```
class MedicalRecord {
    int userId;
    String information;

    public MedicalRecord(int userId, String information) {
      this.userId = userId;
      this.information = information;
    }
  }
```

But other times, when the key is invalid, it returns null, so we filter those out.

```
// Calls a third party service that returns data for some users only
List<MedicalRecord> medicalRecords =
    users.stream()
        .map(user -> Optional.ofNullable(fetchMedicalRecord(user)))
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The task is to generate a report that combines user data with the medical record, but only if the medical record is present. Here is the code that I wrote to do this.

```
return users.stream()
    .filter(
        user -> {
          Optional<MedicalRecord> medicalRecord =
              medicalRecords.stream()
                  .filter(record -> record.userId == user.id)
                  .findFirst();
          return medicalRecord.isPresent();
        })
    .map(
        user -> {
          MedicalRecord medicalRecord =
              medicalRecords.stream()
                  .filter(record -> record.userId == user.id)
                  .findFirst()
                  .get();

          // Both user and medical record are needed here
          return generateReport(user, medicalRecord);
        })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**The problem** - finding a medical record from the list is done twice: once in `filter`, and then in `map`. You could shorten the filter to use something like `anyMatch` but I am not trying to reduce the number of lines here. What I am looking for is a way to pass both the medical record (if present) and the user to `generateReport(user, medicalRecord)` in one go. In theory it might be something that allows map to take two values e.g. `map((user, medicalRecord) -> generateReport(user, medicalRecord))`.

Please note this is a simplified example I just made up to illustrate a problem so ignore minor issues outside of the filter/map scope.

---

If you want a full working example, here are the two functions required to run all this.

```
  private static MedicalRecord fetchMedicalRecord(User user) {
    if (!user.consentKey.equals("tFxn2Ad70")) {
      String information = String.format("%s's medical record", user.name);
      return new MedicalRecord(user.id, information);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  private String generateReport(User user, MedicalRecord medicalRecord) {
    return String.format("%s's report - %s", user.name, medicalRecord.information);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In theory it might be something that allows map to take two values e.g. map((user, medicalRecord) -> generateReport(user, medicalRecord))

We can do so using `Map.Entry`, which can be constructed by [`Map.entry(key, value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)), or create a record class with component `User` and `MedicalRecord`.

```
        users.stream()
                .map(user -> Map.entry(user, Optional.ofNullable(fetchMedicalRecord(user))))
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
                .map(e -> generateReport(e.getKey(), e.getValue().get()))
                .toList();
```

Reference:

[Java - How to create new Entry (key, value)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52426752/7928721)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that for each user you want to find the appropriate medical record. So why wouldn't the following work?

- stream the users
- for each user, stream the medical records until a match is found.
- then generate the report.
- instead of ignoring missing medical records, I tagged them as `NON-EXISTENT`

```
List<String> reports = users.stream().map(user -> {
       MedicalRecord medicalRecord = medicalRecords.stream()
           .filter(record -> Objects.nonNull(record) 
                  && record.userId == user.id)
            .findFirst().orElse(new MedicalRecord(user.id, "NON EXISTENT RECORD"));
              return generateReport(user, medicalRecord);
       }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You might also use an interim record to store user and report and then create a map to map each user to their report.

```
record ReportForUser(User user, String report) {}
        
Map<User,String> reports = users.stream().map(user -> {
    MedicalRecord medicalRecord = medicalRecords.stream()
            .filter(record -> Objects.nonNull(record)
                   && record.userId == user.id)
            .findFirst().orElse(new MedicalRecord(user.id, "NON EXISTENT RECORD"));
     return new ReportForUser(user, generateReport(user, medicalRecord));
}).collect(Collectors.toMap(ReportForUser::user, ReportForUser::report));
```

Comment: It's a good solution, so I upvoted, but preferred the other answer since it deals with null values how I wanted it to (this API shouldn't return users who don't have a record). Appreciate the information though, thanks.