# Android URLConnection POST instead of GET

Tags: android, http-post

I have an app that needs to POST several values to a URL, and return the XML response so that it can be parsed.  Currently, the request is sending the values via the URL.  Below is my current working code, but I'm not able to find any information on the android developers site about POST with URLConnection.  Is it possible?  Any examples?  thank you in advance for any help!

```
          String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/page.cfm";
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(url);
          sb.append("?id=" + id);
          URLConnection conn = new URL(sb.toString()).openConnection();
          conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
          conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
          SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
          SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
          XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
          XMLDataHandler h = new XMLDataHandler();
          xr.setContentHandler(h);
          xr.parse(new InputSource(conn.getInputStream()));
          XMLData = XMLDataHandler.XMLData;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should use HttpURLConnection.
This post may help you:

[How to add parameters to HttpURLConnection using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post)

Comment: I was hoping for a method using the URLConnection, but if I need to switch if over, then I need to switch it over.  thank you jujujuijk!