# ANDROID java.net.URLConnection send image and data at once

Tags: java, android, urlconnection

i use java.net.URLConnection to send image and some parameters to server using POST method. My code below is works fine to send image to server, but i'm bit confused to attach some parameter and send to server in one time. I've followed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486223/1533670) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) but i think its different method with my code.

Here is my snippet code bellow :

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.yai.app.support.DialogHandler;

public class ThreadImageUploader {
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Activity activity;

    public ThreadImageUploader(ProgressDialog mProgressDialog, Activity mActivity){
        dialog = mProgressDialog;
        activity = mActivity;
    }

    public int uploadFile(final String sourceFileUri, final String upLoadServerUri) {
        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;  
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {             
             dialog.dismiss(); 

             Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist : " + sourceFileUri);

             activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     new DialogHandler().customDialog(activity, "ERROR", "Source File not exist : " + sourceFileUri);
                 }
             }); 

             return 0;

        }
        else{
             try { 
                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                 URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                 // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                 conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                 conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                 conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                 conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                 dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='uploaded_file';filename='"
                                           + fileName + "'" + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                 // create a buffer of  maximum size
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                 // read file and write it into form...
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                 while (bytesRead > 0) {
                   dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   
                  }

                 // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                 // Responses from the server (code and message)
                 serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                 String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                 Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                 if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                     activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          public void run() {
                              String message = "File Upload Completed.";                               
                              Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      });                
                 }    

                 //close the streams //
                 fileInputStream.close();
                 dos.flush();
                 dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                dialog.dismiss();  
                ex.printStackTrace();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "MalformedURLException : : check script url.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog.dismiss();  
                e.printStackTrace();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);  
            }
            dialog.dismiss();       
            return serverResponseCode; 

         }
       } 
}
```

How i can send image and some parameter to server in one time? 
many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, here its solution for my problem. The code snippet bellow can use to upload image and send text to server. Maybe this post can help others :)

Here is the code :

```
public int uploadFile(final String sourceFileUri, final String upLoadServerUri, final String renameFile) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;  
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {             
             dialog.dismiss(); 

             Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist : " + sourceFileUri);

             activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     new DialogHandler().customDialog(activity, "ERROR", "Source File not exist : " + sourceFileUri);
                 }
             }); 

             return 0;

        }
        else{
             try {               
                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                 URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                 // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                 conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                 conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                 conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                 conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", renameFile); 

                 dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                 // add parameters
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\""
                         + lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                 // assign value
                 dos.writeBytes("Your value");
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                 // send image
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='uploaded_file';filename='"
                         + renameFile + "'" + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                 // create a buffer of  maximum size
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                 // read file and write it into form...
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                 while (bytesRead > 0) {
                   dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   
                  }

                 // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                 // Responses from the server (code and message)
                 serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                 String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                 Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                 if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                     activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          public void run() {
                              String message = "File Upload Completed.";                               
                              Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      });                
                 }    

                 //close the streams //
                 fileInputStream.close();
                 dos.flush();
                 dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                dialog.dismiss();  
                ex.printStackTrace();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "MalformedURLException : : check script url.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog.dismiss();  
                e.printStackTrace();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);  
            }
            dialog.dismiss();       
            return serverResponseCode; 

         }
       }
```