# java.net.URL.openConnection() to upload 2 text files

Tags: php, android

I am using a `java.net.URL.openConnection()` to upload 2 text files to my server (Android to PHP). I am using a similar code to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093134/android-java-net-urlconnection-send-image-and-data-at-once).  I can get one file uploaded fine but can not figure out how to structure the code for two file.  I believe my problem is related to this code.

```
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='uploaded_file';filename='" + fileName1 + "'" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='uploaded_file2';filename='" + fileName2 + "'" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

Comment: So in short, you wish to upload 2 or more than two files from your android app. M I right ?

Comment: Yes -  upload  two files from my android app

Comment: I tried using only one dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data... line, adding my two files names to a string array, and looping thru the String array  uploadFile(filename) but still only one file gets uploaded.