# GCM registration number to database

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send an app's registration number(which is received by the GCM),straight away to a database table called token_device,when this app is launched. The structure is

```
                      id|int(11)
                  reg_id|varchar(255)
              created_at|timestamp
```

I looked many tutorials that are doing this,but only after the user fills the form and send the data(name,email etc) to the server via a POST request. I don't want to do that. I want the reg_id to be send to the database without any user interaction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For XMPP-based app server setups, you simply send an upstream message to the app server. The app server can get the registration ID from the `from` tag in the message.

For HTTP app server setups, you can send the output of `register(<Sender ID>)` immediately to your web server via HttpURLConnection (or something similar). Do not forget to store the registration ID locally in your Android app's `SharedPreferences`.

Refer to the accepted answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post) for details on how to add the registration ID to your HttpURLConnection parameters.