# Google Glass communicating with App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I am making glassware (with the GDK) that makes a picture, requires a description and sends this data to the App Engine (to my deployed war). The Mirror API should then insert a timeline item in all Glasses that are authenticated to receive messages from this service.

What I do have:

- The logic to push cards to the glasses
- The Glassware running on the Google Glass that can take a picture and make a description by giving a voice command

I would like to know how to post this data to the App Engine so it can use my data to insert timeline items on his turn. I am kinda confused how to do this, because of the authorization I have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `HttpURLConnection` or `DefaultHttpClient` to send the image and its description to your server. Refer to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post) for an example of how to implement this.