# NameValuePair deprecated for openConnection

Tags: java, android, basicnamevaluepair

I been following online tutorials on how to insert data into a database from an android app and have everything working except this small part

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
```

NameValuePair and BasicNameValuePair have been deprecated in favor of `openConnection()`. How can I create a new-value association with that? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()

Does anyone know how I can create name value pairs with openConnection? I been searching everywhere.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `ContentValues`, for example:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("username", name);
values.put("password", password);
database.insert(Table_name, null, values);
```

Comment: `ContentValues` has been design in order to be used by contentresolver NOT network communications - which the question is based on - since there is no `getName()` and `getValue()` methods in case you need to parse header attributes.

Comment: @Hesam you can get the name and values from ContentValues http://stackoverflow.com/a/32559098/4552938

Comment: To me creating an iterator to get the key-values like that seems like marginally extra overhead - I prefer @friederbluemle 's answer below

Answer (score 45):

I just ran into the same problem. The deprecated classes from `org.apache.http` have been **removed** in API `23`.

I ended up using `android.util.Pair`. It works perfectly, and the code is shorter too:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new Pair<>("username", username));
params.add(new Pair<>("password", password));
```

Comment: Thanks, there is also a support library implementation for backwards compatibility

Comment: This is the correct way to achieve this in API level 23

Comment: One thing to note here: Using `android.util.Pair` will create a dependency on the Android framework, so if you want "plain Java" objects that are easily unit testable etc. you can simply use `Map<String, String>` - although that does not allow duplicate keys (which is possible for HTTP headers according to [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)).

Comment: Just to add if you want to get the values as in the example above you can use    (String) params.first and (String) params.second

Comment: this seems to be the better alternative and hence the accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

Alternate to NameValuePair. Also you can get the name and values from it as mentioned below. Here key isa name.

Create:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("key1", "value1");
values.put("key2", "value2");
```

Get key and value :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : values.valueSet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey(); // name
    String value = entry.getValue().toString(); // value
}
```

Comment: Why can't I use Map<String,String> values = new Hashmap<>(); then? What is the advantage of using ContentValues?

Comment: @user1697575  you can use whichever u prefer, my answer was to point hesam comment in accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

you can use contentvalues or hashmap based on your preference.

i have used Content values

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("key1","value1");
contentValues.put("key2","value2");
```

and if the data that u are posting is form data then here`s how u can convert it form data

```
 public String getFormData(ContentValues contentValues) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : contentValues.valueSet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            sb.append("&");

        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        sb.append("=");
        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue().toString(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use httpmime.jar file instead of it, which will work better that NameValuePair. You can Download it from here, [Download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpmime/httpmime-4.3.jar.zip/)

```
MultipartEntity multi = new MultipartEntity();
multi.addPart("name", new StringBody("Raj"));
multi.addPart("Id", new StringBody("011"));
```

add this jar to your project and then use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you realy want to use `NameValuePair` in your application, you can add the `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`  to your gradle:

```
buildtypes{
    //------------
    //----------
}

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Answer (score -46):

Yo can change your android Api in 21, right click, properties android, click in api 21 is work for me

Comment: Changing the compile version and the target is not a solution, just a workaround that will prevent you from using new APIs.

Comment: functions are depreciated as typically a newer, more improved alternative has been included. its counter productive and just incorrect to use this method. id recommend either Content Values as Menna-Allah Sami has provided, or Map<String, String>

Comment: NameValuePair is deprecated in API ver 22. It means It will not use in future.