# android namevaluepair alternate methods

Tags: android

In Andorid  **NameValuePair**,**BasicNameValuePair**
deprecated.
I have

```
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("student",string1));
```

What will be alternative for this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a List of Pair objects, code below from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33072926/4409409):

```
List<Pair<String, String>> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new Pair<>("username", username));
params.add(new Pair<>("password", password));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ContentValues for example

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put("student",string1);
```