# Deprecated HTTP Classes Android lollipop 5.1

Tags: android, http-post

The `org.apache.http` classes and the [AndroidHttpClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) class have been deprecated in Android 5.1. These classes are no longer being maintained and you should migrate any app code using these APIs to the [URLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) classes as soon as possible.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#http

It has recommended to switch to URLConnection classes. There is not enough documented exactly how to make the post call from the app.

Currently i am using this

```
public void postData()
{
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try
    {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     } 
     catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     }
}
```

How can i do it using UrlConnections?

Comment: Do you mean something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post ? I recommend you to switch to Retrofit, aQuery or any other HTTP lib actually.

Comment: Have you checked the official docs?
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: @stan NameValuePair class is deprecated which is used in your shared link accepted answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/2413303

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thought of sharing my code using HttpUrlConnection

```
public String  performPostCall(String requestURL,
            HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            }
            else {
                response="";    

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

..........

```
private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Google sucks. I can't believe that here is no reliable library or wrapper for HTTP requests in Android API.

Answer (score 3):

What about using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)? It seems like a very good choice over URLConnection. And it has a lot of benefits in queueing of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use this httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar
    Try This Code:-

```
String url = "http://www.yoursite.com/script.php";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
try 
{
    entity.addPart("id", new StringBody("123"));
    entity.addPart("stringdata", new StringBody("AndDev is Cool!"));
    postMethod.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response;
    response = client.execute(postMethod);
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
    // ITERATE THROUGH AND RETRIEVE CLUB FIELDS
    int n = ja.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
      // GET INDIVIDUAL JSON OBJECT FROM JSON ARRAYJSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
      // RETRIEVE EACH JSON OBJECT'S FIELDS
      String status = jo.getString("status");
      // Log.e("status",status);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i dont want to use other apache lib... wanted to use UrlConnection