# Flask not receiving POST from Android

Tags: java, android, flask

I used to use DefaultHttpClient for my networking code, but decided to change to HttpURLConnection.

I have searched for other questions on how to send POST messages (eg [How to add parameters to HttpURLConnection using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post)), but for some reason my Flask app always gives me error 400.

When I use logcat, it indeed displays that my POST message is "username=asdf&password=asdf". I include the code below. Also, if I initialized the cookieManager in the method that called this method (makeServiceCall), will returning cookieManager keep my session for subsequent calls to makeServiceCall?

```
public CookieManager makeServiceCall(CookieManager cookieManager, String urlString, int method, List<NameValuePair> db) {
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        if (method == POST) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (db != null) {
                try {
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(out, charset));
                    Log.d("log", "> " + getQuery(db));
                    writer.write(getQuery(db));
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    out.close();

                    //Get Response
                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line;
                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                        response.append('\r');
                    }
                    rd.close();
                    Log.d("Read attempt: ", "> " + response.toString());
                }
                finally {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
```

etc.

Flask code:

```
def login():
  error = None
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME']:
      error = 'Invalid username'
    elif request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
      error = 'Invalid password'
    else:
      session['logged_in'] = True
      flash('You were logged in')
      return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
  return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Comment: Where's the decorator on `login`?

Comment: `my Flask app always gives me error 400.`. App? An app? I see no 400 in your flask code. So what do you mean? Where comes this 400 from?

Comment: `writer.write(getQuery(db));`. We cannot see what gets written there. Wich text is produced by `getQuery(db)` ? You could better temporally or for your stackoverflow conversation put the used text in it.

Comment: `response.append('\r');`. That should be response.append('\n'); or response.append('\r\n');.

Comment: Remove the setChunkedStreamingMode line.

Comment: "Remove the setChunkedStreamingMode line."
This worked! But I don't understand why. Please explain, thank!
BTW error 400 as in HTTP bad request. getQuery will output a string such as "username=asdf&password=asdf". The decorator was there when I pasted it, but it got removed somehow.