# Don't send data via POST with HTTURLCONNECTION on Android

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

(sorry for my bad english)
I have the next code to send data via POST to Server. This code is working in another application correctly. But this does not work now. It's a function that return the response data:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(path);

        HttpURLConnection conecc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conecc.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conecc.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conecc.setDoOutput(true);
        conecc.setDoInput(true);
        conecc.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        conecc.connect();

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter("name", name)
                .appendQueryParameter("birthday", bithday)
                .appendQueryParameter("sex", sex);

        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        OutputStream outputstream = conecc.getOutputStream();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream, "UTF-8"));

        writer.write(query);

        outputstream.close();

        StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conecc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sbuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        //writer.flush();
        //writer.close();
        return sbuilder.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return  null;
    } finally {

        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

On the server i just have this (PHP):

```
print_r($_POST)
```

But i get an empty array. Then connection to server works but data is not sent.

```
Array()
```

I have added these lines before conecc.connect(); unsuccessfully:

```
conecc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
conecc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
conecc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
conecc.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: You can try to add conecc.setRequestMethod("POST");

Comment: I had already added that. But it  still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `conecc.setRequestMethod("POST");` ?

From the rest of your class, there seems to be no typos. But to be sure, check that `String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();` yelds non-null results (just log it, or show as a Toast).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post)  for additional aid in your problem.

### EDIT

Check [this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) for additional ways to fix your issue.

Since you seem to be brazzilian, post in portuguese in the comments if  you cannot writte what you want/need, and we will try to help with that.
I will try to put it simple, [from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post)

```
URL url = new URL("http://YOUR_URL.com");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conecc.setReadTimeout(10000);
conecc.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conecc.setRequestMethod("POST");
conecc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
conecc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
conecc.setDoInput(true);
conecc.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conecc.connect();
```

And in that same class:

```
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;

for (NameValuePair pair : params)
{
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        result.append("&");

    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
    result.append("=");
    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
}

return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: I logged it:
name=PAPANTLA&birthday=1967-07-30&sexo=M

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post seems like a duplicate. But seeing that's older and more relevant, it looks like your answer should've just pointed to the original answer.