# Covert CURL to Java code

Tags: java, curl

I have a CURL as follows. When I call this from the command prompt, after process it returns JSON value. If I access this CURL from PHP also it gives the proper result. Now I want to access this in Java to integrate it to a java project.

```
curl xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/models/images/one.json -XPOST -F job_id=20yy0811-wq50r5-b629 -F image_url=http://www.mysite/public/testimage.jpg
```

I tried to implement it some examples I got from internet, shows HTTP errors like  400, 405 etc.

```
String stringUrl = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/models/images/one.json";
URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

uc.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");
uc.setRequestProperty("format","json");
uc.setRequestProperty("job_id", "20yy0811-wq50r5-b629");
uc.setRequestProperty("image_url", "http://www.mysite/public/testimage.jpg");
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
```

It gives the result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL:
```

Tried another code:

```
String url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/models/images/one.json";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

conn.setRequestProperty("job_id", "20yy0811-wq50r5-b629");
conn.setRequestProperty("image_url", "http://www.mysite/public/testimage.jpg");

String data =  "{\"format\":\"json\"}";
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
out.write(data);
out.close();
new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
```

It gives the result:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
```

My requirement is:

URL: xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/models/images/one.json

Parameters: job_id, image_url

Return value : json

How can I convert this CURL to java code? If someone can change this CURL to Java code it would be great.

SOLUTION:

- Download Apache HttpComponents
- Follow the steps in http://www.journaldev.com/7146/apache-httpclient-example-to-send-get-post-http-requests

  ```
  CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/models/images/one.json");
  //httpPost.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

  List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("job_id", "20yy0811-wq50r5-b629"));
  urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_url", "http://www.mysite/public/testimage.jpg"));


  HttpEntity postParams = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters);
  httpPost.setEntity(postParams);

  CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

  System.out.println("POST Response Status:: "
          + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

  String inputLine;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

  while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      response.append(inputLine);
  }
  reader.close();

  // print result
  System.out.println(response.toString());
  httpClient.close();
  ```

Comment: parameters are url form encoded parameters or header values?

Comment: Yes, one parameter is an image url.

Comment: The `-F` for cURL is for multipart data. Add the `-v` switch to the request to see all the headers. You will see. If you don't know how to properly format multipart data, then I suggest looking into a library that already implements such feature.

Comment: Jusing Apache HttpClient is way easier that HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: @peeskillet, How do I pass -v  and -F?

Comment: On the command line with your curl request. I am not saying that is a solution. I am just saying to get verbose output on the curl request, use the `-v` switch. This will only give you more information about your curl request. I said to do that just so you can see that the request is a multipart request, based on your use of `-F` switches for your data. Like I said, if you know nothing about multipart and it's format, you should look into a library that can send multipart. Formatting the output is not easy for someone who has no understanding of the output

Comment: @Michael-O, do you have a sample code?

Comment: @san http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setRequestProperty()` sets the headers.To set Form parameters, try this:

```
String url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/models/images/one.json";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

//build it this way
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
        .appendQueryParameter("firstParam", paramValue1)
        .appendQueryParameter("secondParam", paramValue2)
        .appendQueryParameter("thirdParam", paramValue3);
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(query);
writer.flush();
```

You need to import ApacheHttpClient lib to use `Uri.Builder` class.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29053050/856007

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8. for Uri.Builder class which jar I need to import?. it seems Uri.Builder is for Android.

Comment: you need to import ApacheHttpClient

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much it's working now! I have followed the code in http://www.journaldev.com/7146/apache-httpclient-example-to-send-get-post-http-requests