# android InputStream cannot get inout from server page

Tags: android, inputstream, urlconnection

Hi I am using the following code but I cannot get the `iStream` from the `url`. The url returns a JSON Array.

```
URL url = new URL(tomato_search);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream iStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
readStream(iStream);
iStream.close();
```

Comment: Perhaps you need call urlConnection.connect() before getInputStream()

Comment: nothing happened my php file is: print(json_encode($output));

Comment: Try check resp code, if it is >=400, getErrorStream instead getInputStream

Comment: can you show my how to add this in my code?

Comment: You can take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post/31888919#31888919)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using http to communicate, better to use HttpURLConnection.

```
JsonArray jsonArray;
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.example.com/endpoint").openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
httpURLConnection.connect();
InputStream is = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (br.readLine() != null) {
            sb.append(br.readLine()).append("\n");
        }
        br.close();

        jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        jsonArray = null;
    }
```

Comment: I just want to get the inputstream return because then I am using the readstream(iStream) method to get the Json object like:{
        JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(in);
        for(int i=0; i<jarray.length();i++){
            Food_Model food = new Food_Model();
            JSONObject c= jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            //Integer id = c.getInt("food_id");
            food.setFood_id(c.getInt("food_id"));
            food.setFood_name(c.getString("food_description"));
            food.setProtein(Double.parseDouble(c.getString("food_protein")));
            foodlist.add(food);

Comment: I use this code to get data (json object/ array) from my server. I did a bad copy past sorry. Check again the code ;)

Comment: Sry for the questions but I am a bit confuse. Why do you use a String and the new line char to get the inputstream? and what is the Constants.DEBUG... for?

Comment: Sorry I removed the debug line and the String line. So when you get the InputStream and because you are looking for a json format (usually a string), you will have to InputStreamReader to transform a stream of bytes to a stream of characters. Then you have the BufferedReader which will buffered lines. So from each line of this BufferedReader, you will build string and then use this string to build your JsonArray.

Comment: I am still getting an error at the httpURLConnection.connect(); method

Comment: Can you post what log cat outputs ? connect sould give you an IOException.

Comment: 09-07 12:23:55.090    3024-3038/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-07 12:23:55.090    3024-3038/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabee9380, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: Seems that the problem does not come from an IOException :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89000/discussion-between-charilaos13-and-xiaomi).