# How to send the post data to a website using Httpurlconnection

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

I wrote a code for receiving the data but I don't know how to send the post data to the server.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;

    try{
        url=new URL("http://mysite/create.php");

        String param="name=" + URLEncoder.encode("hello","UTF-8");

        conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.print(param);
        out.close();

        String response= "";

        Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());

        while(inStream.hasNextLine())
            response+=(inStream.nextLine());

    }
    catch(MalformedURLException ex){


    }
    catch(IOException ex){


    }
}

}
```

But no response while executing it. I am running it IntelliJ Jetbrains IDE.

Comment: Try using BasicNameValuePair, like suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post

Comment: But namevaluepair is deprecated@amupoti

Comment: Get rid of `catch(IOException ex){ }` and the other empty catch block and you might be able to figure out what's wrong

Comment: even though no response. It is showing response code as 500 @artbristol

Comment: Um, 500 is not "no response", it's `internal server error`. At this point I'd check with the server folks, if possible, and maybe peek at their logs, if possible. It is not at all unlikely that they didn't validate their input and they should be outputting `bad request`, though (as in, *your* request is broken).