# Android HttpURLConnection and JSON

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I have maybe a very simple question, but I cannot get the solution.

What I want to do is send a POST to my Webservice with UserID and Password as JSON parameters and receive back from the Webservice a JSON with the user information.

I have googled around but can't find any real sample how to do this. Does anyone has a solution?

I am using Android Studio latest version and have to change to HttpURLConnection as the before used HTTPClient is no longer available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add parameters to HttpURLConnection using POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post)

Comment: Your webservice is Asp.Net WebAPI, isn't it?