# HTTP Post from Android app not working as expected

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Trying to register a user into the database.

This code works:

```
try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.jacksteel.co.uk/Comp4/registeruser.php?" + getQuery(userData));
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(userData));
            Log.d("myTag", getQuery(userData));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            Log.d("myTag",conn.getInputStream().toString());


            conn.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However this code does not:

```
 try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.jacksteel.co.uk/Comp4/registeruser.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(userData));
            Log.d("myTag", getQuery(userData));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            Log.d("myTag",conn.getInputStream().toString());


            conn.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The only difference being that I concatenated the result of getQuery() onto the end of the URL, which suggests that the HTTP post is not working, I got the code fore the Post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post) I already have the data in a nameValuePair list called 'userData'

So, my question is why does it not work without appending `getQuery(userData)` to the URL, and can I make it work?

Comment: What's the error you get when it doesn't work?

Comment: @DanielNugent I don't get an error it just doesn't insert anything into the database

Comment: What is the full response from the server when it doesn't work?

Comment: @DanielNugent just noticed i had the line `Log.d("myTag",conn.getInputStream().toString());` commented out, uncommented it and tried again, same thing happens except in both cases this time i get the following error for that log line: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.jacksteel.co.uk/comp4/registeruser.php`

Comment: Strange.  Try calling `conn.connect()` before logging `conn.getInputStream()`.  Also try moving the logging to the place where you successfully got a result when it was working.

Comment: I suspect the first experiment is performing a GET request. Strip out all the outputstream part to test it. Also, are you sure that the registeruser.php does accept POST requests?

Comment: Got it working without appending `getQuery(userData)` but it still throws the FileNotFoundException at the logging, even after moving `conn.connect` above it