# I want to send Http request in marshmallow android?

Tags: java, android, url, http-post, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am beginner for android application. I develop android application and its my first application. I develop android application for all version of Android, my application based on URL request, means I have to send URL request for every action. I faced problem for marshmallow android version, because It isn't support Http Post method.

I developed program successfully in JAVA to send request for login action. Same code try to implement in Android code, I faced problem.

I have to send request like "https://www.veejansh.com/vurja/mobile.php?action=login&username=abc@xyz.com&password=blabla".

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.omg.CORBA.NameValuePair;

/**
 *
 * @author tejaskumar
 */
public class tryHttp2 {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter("https.useragent", "Test Client");

        BufferedReader br = null;

        PostMethod method = new PostMethod("https://www.veejansh.com/vurja/mobile.php");
        method.addParameter("action", "login");
        method.addParameter("username","abc@xyz.com");
        method.addParameter("password","blabla");

        try{
            int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
            if(returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
                System.err.println("The Post method is not implemented by this URI");
                // still consume the response body
                method.getResponseBodyAsString();
            } else {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
                String readLine;
                while(((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                    System.out.println(readLine);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
            if(br != null) try { br.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Give some advice for all version of android, or any other good method to achieve this task. I try to find best way to develop this task.

I also try to add .jre file org.apache.http.legacy, but gradle cannot find this file. I also add permission for INTERNET.

Can I achieve this task with use of JSON request? If yes, then how?
Please give some example to achieve this task.

I got error on this line : int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);

I got one more error : Gradle sync failed: Stub! 
So I cannot run SDK and cannot build project successfully.

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Comment: Or even better, a fully framework like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Comment: @Dhaval Patel or someone else: Is it still possible to send http requests with 6.0 and HttpURLConnection (instead of https)?

Comment: @skymedium yes, of Course.

Comment: Thx for the response. In the origin question it sounds to me like "no http calls in 6.0 supported".

Comment: This link would be helpful to solve your problem [How to add parameters to HttpURLConnection using POST](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13486223/5629056)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Boolean excutePost(String targetURL, JSONObject jsonParam)
    {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(targetURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // hear you are telling that it is a POST request, which can be changed into "PUT", "GET", "DELETE" etc.
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"); // here you are setting the `Content-Type` for the data you are sending which is `application/json`
            connection.connect();

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream ());
            wr.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close ();

            InputStream is;
            int response = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (response >= 200 && response <=399){
                //return is = connection.getInputStream();
                return true;
            } else {
                //return is = connection.getErrorStream();
               return false;
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        } finally {

            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)
2. To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

   android {
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
   }

Comment: I already tried to add org.apache.http.legacy but gradle cannot find this file. I also add this file in app/lib but still faced a problem.
I show example related to HttpUrlConnection, but I cannot find way to send parameter with URL.
`URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }`
Please tell me how to send parameters in above code.
Thanks @taruna sharma

Comment: You are trying to utilize legacy classes, this is not recommended