# HttpURL connection what is the recommended value for setConnectionTimeout and setReadTimeOut?

Tags: android

I Want to know what is the recommended value for methods `setConnectionTimeou()` and 
`setReadTimeOut()` for HttpURL connection? I know these value depends upon the server and what task server is performing. but still i want to know the recommended values for these method.

Comment: If you don't know, then just leave it at the defaults.

Comment: Thanks, but we talking about the recommended values for these methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer such question without knowing the typical response time. Users are fairly accustomed to wait a few seconds when using mobile devices whilst on mobile networks.

Personally if the timeout is between 10 - 15s I will consider it a normal latency, if it is 20s or more, I will most likely quit the app.

From Default  [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)

Both setConnectTimeout (int timeout) and setReadTimeout (int timeout) From API 1

A SocketTimeoutException is thrown if the connection could not be established in this time. **Default is 0 which stands for an infinite timeout.**

see this link its give you more idea about this.

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/website-response-times/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this example:
Your method
[How to add parameters to HttpURLConnection using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post/13486223#13486223)

OR

You can follow this other form
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Please dont post just links. Copy code to your answer.