# How can i store currentlocation into databse using GoogleMap?

Tags: android, google-maps

How can i store currentlocation into database using GoogleMap?I am using one url for storing currentlocation into database....

```
https://182.50.133.175/dgrid55/15/index.php
```

.java file

```
      URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(strUrl);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                connection.getOutputStream());

        outputStreamWriter.write("latitude=" + lat + "&logitude="+lng);
        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        outputStreamWriter.close();

        InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";

        while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        reader.close();
        iStream.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in adavace

Comment: used retrofit it is easy for network calling application

Answer (score 1):

If your server accept POST You can do that like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486223/6950238) answer:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lat));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("logitude", lng));
```

then

```
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
```

Comment: Without Json can i store data to databse?

Comment: It depends on server-side implementation.

Comment: Can i store my Google map Current Location in database(MySQL) without webservice?

Comment: No. You should have something, which receives your data from request ans stores it in appropriate database fields.

Comment: Is webservices compulsory for current location store in database?

Comment: That is different question. When You sent some data from your app what will receive it? What will parse it and creates INSERT INTO query for MySQL? So You need some server-side code for receiving, process and store data. It can be php, python, java or other language script. You can take a look at [this](http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~hankley/d764/tut06/GopisettyPHP.html) tutorial (instead of the web form will be your Android application)