# Http post how to add parameter to my URL

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I want to add my Fbid to php DB , how can I do this?

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... data) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient
            URL url = new URL(data[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fbid", fbid));

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(params));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            connection.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }


    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

My `compileSdkVersion` is 24 and `buildToolsVersion` "24.0.1".
Why I cant add to the db? Is that because `NameValuePair` is deprecated?

Comment: This is not PHP, this is C#

Comment: can you elaborate your query? Please let us know what is the output you are expecting and what is the actual hurdle you've faced.

Comment: if I got my fbid 1111111111111111 , i want to add that fbid to my db to do like sign in , my code referenced from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post 
if my code was wrong , how can i do to fix it , hope someone can help me

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i dont have error , but my db got nothing .

Comment: Show your PHP code.

Comment: thanks guys , I have done to fix it . I just forgot to write some code
private HttpAsyncTask 
GetDataTask;GetDataTask = new HttpAsyncTask();
GetDataTask.execute(URL);