# Android - Sending JSON request to server

Tags: android, arrays, json, post

I'm a newly in Android programming.
My issue is this:
I would like to send a JSON request like by Post method from an android app.

The request is this:

```
{"username": "jde",
 "password": "oracle01",
 "inputs" : 
[ 
  {   "name": "Username", "value": "COCCONIP" },
  {   "name" : "Surname", "value" : "Cocconi" } 
] 
 }
```

someone could help me ?
Regards
Paolo

Comment: instead of downvote guide him how to send data or post data to the server.

Comment: google for retrofit/okhttp examples

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using HttpClient? Actually Android deprecates HttpClient insted of HttpClient you need to "HttpURLConnection" for POST Request check Here one of the sample : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post/13486223#13486223)

That link answers tou your question