# How do I write POST method in Android

Tags: android, post

Here is my code so far, please assist me, I need a to sign into the website using post method username and password.  I looked up examples online and used the wiki how to do this.  I set everything inside of the button click as you see:

```
package com.example.work.try1;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.OutputStream; 
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Launch extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);

    final View buttonS = findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.navanithiastrolife.com");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            String username = e1.getText().toString();
            EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            String password = e2.getText().toString();

            OutputStream out = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://iconinfo.tech/mob_app/");

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.connect();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("username",username);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("password",password);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                urlConnection.disconnect();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Please assist, ok thx.

Comment: just use the retrofit

Comment: you need a background thread for network operation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486223/3635454

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

you also use the [volley library](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Networking-with-the-Volley-Library)  to call the API

i hope its helpful to you ..!

Comment: I want to post to php, volley uses JSON which looks like java?

Comment: yes its use JAVA..!
you cam also send the POST Request..!

Answer (score 0):

Your request is being done in the main thread, this is not right because it can block the main thread.  For this background operation you must use a background thread such as Volley library, Retrofit or RoboSpice. To build the POST method you have to construct the data your post will contain.  For example, In Volley you use a key value pair approach.

Comment: I am posting to php not to java, so I can still use volley or JSON?  or do I have to use post?