# How do contents in name value pair pass as arguments in Android Studio?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, http

Suppose i have this

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pin", "date"));
```

And When i use the following code

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://X.X.X.X/abcdef.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

what will be the post request? How will the arguments pass in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer
can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9767952/8668843) for more details

arguments are passed as this

```
http://localhost/xyz.php?pin=date&package=123&requirements=xxx&last_date=25%20april
```