# Sorting ArrayList without sorting the index in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have `ArrayList` which contains a value and index, how can i sort the value without sorting the index?

example:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 arr.add(1,100);
 arr.add(2,50);
 arr.add(3,10);
```

the result will be {(3,10),(2,50),(1,100)}
thanks :D

Comment: Are you sure that this is an `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: But sorting MEANS changing the index.

Comment: I would guess by the downvotes and votes to close that you're not being clear.  a sorted arraylist of integers would just be [10,50,100], there's no concept of "sorting the index".  It's either sorted, or it isn't sorted.

Comment: An `ArrayList` only stores a single value, not two. You're probably looking for a `Map`...

Comment: It is a nonsense. Index is ever belong to order.

Comment: @MartinStrejc It's not *that* nonsensical. It sounds like the OP wants to sort the array, but while also keeping track of what the index of an element was before it was sorted.

Comment: wrong data for `List<Integer>` data structure.

Comment: Oke, maybe i am wrong so what the structure i should use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the `Map` option, you can consider using some sort of Key value pair and, storing that in your array and sort your array based on the values.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973041/a-keyvaluepair-in-java) for potential key value pairs, or make your own.

An example:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class KeyValue {

    private int key;
    private Integer value;

    public KeyValue(int i, Integer j) {
        key  = i;
        value = j;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<KeyValue> arr = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();
        arr.add(new KeyValue(1, 100));
        arr.add(new KeyValue(2, 50));
        arr.add(new KeyValue(3, 10));
        Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<KeyValue>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(KeyValue arg0, KeyValue arg1) {
                return Integer.compare(arg0.getValue(), arg1.getValue());
            }

        });
        for (KeyValue kv : arr){
            System.out.println(kv);
        }
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "("+key+","+value.toString()+")";                
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking doesn't make sense because an element's index is directly tied to how it is sorted. You should use a `Map` or something similar.

Comment: Actually i confused what structure i must use. i want to classified an image using knn and euclidean distance. the distance is the difference between RGB of each image. So i need to sort the distance and classified it to the nearest image..